# Can't have conditional in SwiftUI ForEach

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm learning SwiftUI at the moment. I've been playing around with loading a list from CoreData and making changes on / filtering etc. I've run into the issues below. Essentially as soon as I try to apply any conditionals within the ForEach I I'm presented with that error.

This works if I run iterate through the organisations in List itself rather than a ForEach. This isn't the ideal solution as I loose the inbuilt deletion function.

Am I missing something stupid?

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

@EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@FetchRequest(entity: Organisation.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Organisation.name, ascending: true)])
var orgs: FetchedResults<Organisation>


var body: some View
{
    NavigationView {
        
        List {
            
            ForEach(orgs, id: \.self) {org in
                
                if !self.userData.showFavsOnly || org.isFavorite {
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: OrganisationView(org: org, moc: self.managedObjectContext)) {
                        
                        OrganisationRow(org: org)
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

There error code I get is I get is on the for each line and is

```
Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can
> conform to protocols

This error means that your `ForEach` loop expects some View. But you give it an `if-statement` instead. What if the condition returns false?

The solution may be to wrap the `if-statement` in some View - it could be a `Group`, `VStack`, `ZStack`...

```
ForEach(orgs, id: \.self) { org in
    Group {
        if !self.userData.showFavsOnly || org.isFavorite {
            NavigationLink(destination: OrganisationView(org: org, moc: self.managedObjectContext)) {
                OrganisationRow(org: org)
            }
        }
    }
}
```